# Tensorflow: Load pre-trained model weights into a different architecture

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I have a Tensorflow model that works reasonably well for detecting an object in an image and generating a bounding rectangle. The output includes one Softmax and 4 analog values for location. I need to add one more analog output for predicting the object orientation. How can I import the pre-trained model weights and freeze them so that only the part dealing with the orientation in the last layer will be trained.